# Why i am getting Server error 500 when i upload my app to server

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, server, laravel-5

I just deployed my application to my server. I zipped my whole app folder and uploaded that to my server. I also exported the database tables of my app and imported that to my server phpmyadmin. I have configured `.env` settings but when I try to access my app it throws Server error 500. My app is located at `mywebsite.com/app/` all files resides in the app folder. I also tried to move public file to `public_html` but still it is not working.

**.env File:**

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:keyofmyapp
APP_URL=http://mywebsite.com

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD='password'

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

**Logs :**

```
[14-Apr-2016 19:35:44 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php on line 50
[14-Apr-2016 19:36:40 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php on line 50
[14-Apr-2016 19:38:21 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php on line 50
[14-Apr-2016 19:38:27 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php on line 50
[14-Apr-2016 19:38:47 UTC] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/index.php on line 21
[14-Apr-2016 19:38:47 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/index.php on line 21
[14-Apr-2016 19:41:40 UTC] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/index.php on line 21
[14-Apr-2016 19:41:40 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/index.php on line 21
[14-Apr-2016 19:41:44 UTC] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/index.php on line 21
[14-Apr-2016 19:41:44 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/index.php on line 21
[14-Apr-2016 19:42:40 UTC] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/index.php on line 21
[14-Apr-2016 19:42:40 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/index.php on line 21
[14-Apr-2016 19:43:15 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php on line 50
[14-Apr-2016 19:43:17 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php on line 50
[14-Apr-2016 19:43:19 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php on line 50
[14-Apr-2016 19:45:11 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php on line 50
[14-Apr-2016 19:45:15 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php on line 50
[14-Apr-2016 19:45:17 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php on line 50
[14-Apr-2016 19:45:26 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php on line 50
[14-Apr-2016 19:46:22 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php on line 50
[14-Apr-2016 19:48:27 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php on line 50
[14-Apr-2016 19:50:35 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php on line 50
[14-Apr-2016 19:52:03 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php on line 50
[14-Apr-2016 19:52:05 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php on line 50
[14-Apr-2016 19:56:40 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php on line 50
[14-Apr-2016 19:56:49 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/ushrzaka/public_html/mywebsite.com/pos/public/index.php on line 50
```

Comment: It could be one of many things.  If the PHP version is different, it could be a syntax error, there are many server settings which could have this affect, maybe Apache is missing mod_rewrite.  Looking at the error logs should give you a good idea.

Comment: check for log files. that will give you and us some clues.

Comment: 500 is a general server error, and could mean a vast array of issues as stated above. Check the server logs, read the errors, change your server config to expose the errors to client (debug mode on).

Comment: logs added please check @tanaydin

Comment: don't upload public folder. just upload its content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using PHP < 5.5. Laravel 5.2 requires version PHP 5.5.9 and looking at line 50 of index.php there is:

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
```

and [class name resolution](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name) was added in PHP 5.5.

So you should verify your PHP version. It's probably 5.4 or earlier

Comment: you can make it with a file only contains <?php phpinfo(); ?>